# Start javascript script whent onclick

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a question,

I would that my javascript code starts when there is an onclick event on my link.

Javascript code is very simple because is Google Analytics code.

I tried to use a function (anal.. yes is funny):

```
<script>
function anal() {
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', '<my ua Code>', 'auto');  
ga('send', 'pageview');
}
</script>
```

called by

```
 <div id="video_overlays" onclick='anal();' >
```

but didn't work.

Where I wrong?

####SOLVED

```
 <script> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    function anal() {
    ga('create', 'UA-myCode-1', 'auto');  // Replace with your property ID.
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    }
    </script>
```

and:

```
<div id="video_overlays" onclick='anal();' >
```

..and works!

Comment: Do you mean: when a link clicked  Google analytic starts? am I right?

Comment: You can ask this question in Google support too

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question. Where is the `onClick='anal();'` being called?

Comment: This looks really weird. For general data collection purposes, you should include GA to every page. You'd want a virtual pageview or connect the anal() event with some different code in my opinion. But it is unclear what questioner wants to achieve in my opinion. But since he wrote SOLVED then perhaps it is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set event tracking on your website So, Simply calling out your function will not work.
Try this.. It might help

```
<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                              //instead of auto you can put your domain name.
  ga('create', '<my ua Code>', 'auto');  
  ga('send', 'pageview');
 }
</script>
```

and then call it by:

```
<div id="video_overlays" onclick='ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Click', 'Details');'>
```